# Jersey ClientResponse getCookies failing to parse correctly

Tags: java, cookies, jersey-client

I have some Java code which is calling a restful service, and needs to first authenticate and store cookies for a future call.  I am using Jersey 1.8.  The problem is that after making the call to authenticate, I try to retrieve the cookies using ClientResponse.getCookies() and iterate through the list of NewCookie objects.  However, when calling NewCookie.getName(), the path of the cookie is returned.

The cookies returned in the response header look like this:

Set-Cookie: xsIdEEDB0766347B60DAEAA0AF57226EDD2C=385DF57B79FE0A4D84E04ED43000A81B; path=/; HttpOnly

My code looks something like this. I am just dumping the info to System.out for now because I wanted to look at the values in the debugger.

My question is why ClientResponse.getCookies() does not seem to work. Parsing the headers manually will work, but that just does not seem right.  Is there a way to configure the Client or the ClientResponse to correctly get the cookies?

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);

Builder builder = client.resource(MY_PATH).accept("text/plain");
builder = builder.header(AUTHORIZATION, auth);

ClientResponse response = builder.head();

if (response.getClientResponseStatus() == Status.OK) {

    // Look at cookies in the response
    List<NewCookie> cs = response.getCookies();
    for (NewCookie c : cs) {
        System.out.println(c.getName());
        System.out.println(c.getValue());
    }

    // Look at the cookies in the header
    List<String> cookies  = headers.get("Set-Cookie");
    for (String cookie : cookies) {
        // example: xsIdEEDB0766347B60DAEAA0AF57226EDD2C=385DF57B79FE0A4D84E04ED43000A81B; path=/; HttpOnly
        int x = cookie.indexOf(';');
        String cookieNameValue = cookie.substring(0, x); 
        String[] nameValue = cookieNameValue.split("=");
        NewCookie nc = new NewCookie(nameValue[0], nameValue[1]);

    }
}
```